# Static ip getting released

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dhcp, static-ip

I am setting up static ip in ubuntu 18.04 using /etc/network/interfaces file.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto en0 
iface en0 inet static
   address 10.10.10.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Thereafter, i am using below command to implement static ip
`sudo ifconfig en0 down` and
`sudo ifup en0 up`

on checking ifconfig i find ip as 10.10.10.1 for en0 but after sometime it is released and just hardware address appear.

Please let me know if there are any possible explanation.

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` system is deprecated in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. I suggest that you revert your changes and use netplan. If you are using Network Manager, I'd make my changes there. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Probably it was overwritten by the _NetworkManager_ dhcp client or was in conflict with other resources (IPs) on your Network. Check your available and detected interfaces with `nmcli dev status`

Comment: an alternative is to set your static ip using your router (usually 192.168.1.1)

Comment: @chili555 in our system, we are using wpa_supplicant for wifi interface and handling ethernet interface using interfaces file. Is it ok if we switch to netplan for ethernet ? and Thanks for your help

Comment: @BodoHugoBarwich `nmcli dev status` is showing ethernet interface. If dhclient is overwriting, so can i specify static ip for ethernet in my dhclient config file. will that work?

Comment: @User24601 you are suggesting to set IP in router for this particular mac address?

Comment: Yes. It's what I have done. It also avoids conflicts with other devices (android, tablets etc) competing for ip addresses on the common network.

Comment: "in our system, we are using wpa_supplicant for wifi interface and handling ethernet interface using interfaces file. Is it ok if we switch to netplan for ethernet ? " Why not simply use netplan for both!?

Comment: if the `nmcli` shows the device as "_managed_" it is very likely that the _NetworkManager_ has reset your changes. So you need to set the Settings in the _NetworkManager_ . Now for a graphical Desktop it is the easiest to do this with the Network Applet. For a Server I usually do it using the `nmcli` command. That way your settings will be save from future updates.